# Configure Jenkins JDK installations Programmatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm looking to configure Jenkins JDK installations programmatically, either through the CLI or by writing XML files.

I know I can amend the config.xml file (main one) to include JDK installations but I'd prefer to have it configured in a separate file. (e.g hudson.tasks.Ant.xml)

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to do it :) Just call this: `jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getJDKs().add(new hudson.model.JDK("id", "path"))`